# How to dynamically tighten height for TabView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

The `TabView` seems to stretch to its maximum height, but I'd like it to shorten to height as much as it requires instead of empty space. This is what it looks like even tho there are `Spacer` views around it:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Some text")
        Text("Some text")
        Text("Some text")
        Spacer()
        TabView {
            GroupBox(label: Text("This is the title 1")) {
                Label("Some item 1", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 2", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 3", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 4", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
            }
            .padding()
            GroupBox(label: Text("This is the title 2")) {
                Label("Some item 1", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 2", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 3", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 4", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
            }
            .padding()
            GroupBox(label: Text("This is the title 3")) {
                Label("Some item 1", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 2", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 3", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                Label("Some item 4", systemImage: "checkmark.circle.fill")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .background(Color.yellow)
        Spacer()
        Text("Some text")
        Text("Some text")
        Text("Some text")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically tighten the height to what's needed by its children?

Comment: Did my answer fix the issue?

Comment: It caused weird layout issues, probably more related to my specific app. But did get me closer.. Thx!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `.frame( height: .leastNormalMagnitude)`

```
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
.background(Color.yellow)
.frame( height: .leastNormalMagnitude)
```

---

The Page Index covers the views. You probably need to give GroupBoxes a 40-50 points padding bottom or change indexViewStyle's background.

```
 .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
```

Comment: not working, my tabview disappeared

Comment: this does no longer work

Comment: not working at all